# Best way to notify external users when a specific catalog item is ordered?

Tags: notifications, servicenow

I need to notify external people, non-ServiceNow users, when a specific Item is ordered.
I tried using the email notification using a condition. But somehow I wasn't able to work it out. 
What would the the most efficient way to make this happen?

I can't refer to a specific item when I select the sc_req_item table as condition. So I probably need a small workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to specify a specific Catalog Item, I tested this on Geneva and it worked.

Try something like the notification configuration below and put an order in for the Catalog Item you configured? If it doesn't work, can you post what you've put in for your notification?

You should see emails for these under one of these depending on your environment.

- *System Mailboxes* > *Outbound* > *Sent*
- *System Mailboxes* > *Outbound* > *Outbox*

---

Table: Requested Item [sc_req_item]

**When to send**

- Inserted: Checked
- Conditions

  - Item is **Google Nexus 7** (Switch this to your Catalog Item)

**Who will receive**

- Users

  - vendor1@example.com
  - vendor2@example.com

**What it will contain**

- Email template: sc_req_item.itil.role

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a Workflow runscript activity in that particular Catalog Item to create an event to send notification to External users? You can pass the external email ID easily while calling the event for triggering the notification.